# How do I change the shell for php's exec()

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu, exec

I want to use php's exec() function on an ubuntu server.
The problem is, I alway get an error, that the command is not found. For example using

```
exec("echo 123");
```

prints

> sh: /echo: not found

To me, it looks like php is using the sh shell, when I want to be using bash.
I tried changing the shell for www-data in /etc/passwd, that didn't help either.

Does anybody have an idea where else the problem might be coming from or how I can change the shell for php's ubuntu user.

Thanks, Timo

---

[EDIT]

Maybe this helps:

I call a bash script from ssh as timo, this script calls a php script, which uses exec. I know, it sounds weird, but it's part of a bigger development environment...

The point is, I'm not ever certain, as which user the script inside exec is executed.

---

[EDIT]

By now I figured out that there must be another rights problem involved.
Even if I try calling a bash script test.sh (by it's full path!) from within exec, php test.php will just say.

> sh: /test.sh: not found

Answer (score 15):

Try shell_exec() instead.    exec should not invoke ANY shell to execute your program.    Alternately, you can invoke bash with exec like

```
exec("/bin/bash -c \"echo $foo > bar.txt'\"")
```

Comment: this will just say "sh: /bash: not found". looks like php searches for all the binaries in /. in php.ini safe_mode_exec_dir is set to nothing, so i guess that means, there are no restrictions!? (changing it doesn't seem to help)

Comment: I have no experience with safe mode so perhaps that is your problem.  Try turning it off?   You shouldn't be using it anyway, it's going away and was a bad idea from the beginning (list most PHP language "features") http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

Comment: Didn't notice someone had mentioned this already - agreed safe mode is Considered Harmful. Regarding safe_mode_exec_dir, if safe mode is on and this is set to empty then that would explain it (if you want to run anything it would need to set to /). I suggest you try setting it to something meaningful and invoking something in that path.

Comment: I used shell_exec(), but this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that there is no $PATH setup. Try using full paths to your binaries ie 
    /bin/echo

Comment: Thanks for you super quick reply.
Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. /bin/echo doesn't work either.

What I actually wanted to do is this

/usr/bin/mysql --user=asdf --password=asdf mydb < ./dump.sql

As you can see, I even used the absolute path. The echo was just an example to make it more simple...

Any other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is:

`/usr/bin/mysql --user=asdf --password=asdf mydb < ./dump.sql`

Then I imagine this would work (regardless of shell):

`/usr/bin/mysql --user=asdf --password=asdf mydb < /full/path/to/dir/dump.sql`

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure how to actually set the shell in PHP, but you could call a script from sh with "#!/bin/bash" as it's first line, if you really do need bash (and can't find another way to do it).

Comment: the problem is not, that my dump cannot be found, but rather mysql can't be found...

Comment: If there really is a binary installed at /usr/bin/mysql then sh would find it and the problem is something else - like maybe safe-mode is enabled (checkout the docs for safe-mode-exec-dir and similar). Another thing to check is open_basedir, which can also limit what exec has access too.

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP calls /bin/sh internally (or cmd.exe on Windows) regardless of which function you use.

Running `ls -l /proc/$$/exe | sed 's%.*/%%'` in your terminal in a Linux system should tell you what shell you're using, which is bash in my Ubuntu terminal by default. If you run the following in Ubuntu:

```
<?php

exec('ls -l /proc/$$/exe | sed \'s%.*/%%\'', $res);
// or:
//$res = shell_exec('ls -l /proc/$$/exe | sed \'s%.*/%%\'');
echo(json_encode($res));
```

you will get ["dash"] as the result, regardless of which function you use.  If you change /bin/sh to point to bash rather than dash, the result from PHP changes to bash, but I don't recommend doing that obviously.

So long story short it's probably not possible to change this without modifying your entire server's default shell or compiling PHP from source.

If you want to solve the mystery further, it's probably related to ext/standard/proc_open.c and ext/standard/exec.c (all these functions are in there, system, passthru, etc.) in the PHP source, but to be honest it beats me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with Debian Docker PHP image, this helped me:

https://www.reliableembeddedsystems.com/wiki/index.php?title=Make_bash_default_shell

`/bin/sh` was a symlink to dash, which may be better but doesnt work with my scripts.

```
        echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
        dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive dash
```