# Exec with PHP-FPM on nginx (under chroot) returns nothing

Tags: nginx, php, chroot

I've created a nginx server in a chroot at /srv/http with php-fpm. Both services use the http user and it works fine. The problem comes when I try to run an exec command such as

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/ls');
```

There is no output at all on the web page or in the errors. I've also tried

```
error_log(shell_exec('/usr/bin/ls');
```

and still nothing.

Things I've Tried or Know:

1. safe mode off
2. exec enabled
3. user is http (using phpinfo())
4. display_errors = on
5. error_reporting = E_ALL
6. sudo /usr/bin/chroot --userspec=http:http /srv/http ls works fine
7. Can create file and read from it using file_puts_content and fopen/fread
8. tried shell_exec,exec,system, and passthrough - nothing worked
9. tried appending 2>&1 to the end of the command and nothing
10. I've copied all the executables and libraries necessary over
11. all libraries, binaries, and everything under /srv/http/www (where the webpages are) have executable and read permissions
12. doc_root is www

As far as I know, everything works in the chroot, except shell commands through php-fpm. Anyone have any idea where I went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid but you must just copy `/bin/sh` (not `/bin/bash`!) to you `chroot`.

For example see this question: [How do I change the shell for php's exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792643/how-do-i-change-the-shell-for-phps-exec)

Comment: Also use `ldd sh` to find what libraries it needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you `chroot` to some directory, then this directory becomes the root for all your PHP scripts. That means, that if you execute `/usr/bin/ls` from within PHP, it will try to exectue `/srv/http/usr/bin/ls` instead.

You can copy the executable to that directory - but be aware of the security implications. If you copy critical system executables into the chrooted directory you basically bypass the positive effects of `chroot`.

Comment: I did this already. I copied /usr/bin/ls to /srv/http/usr/bin/ls ( and after seeing the libraries needed with ldd /srv/http/usr/bin/ls ), I copied the .so files to /srv/http/usr/lib. And it still didn't work. And see #6 where I can run it within the chroot, so I have the files needed.

Answer (score 0):

I get no output for

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/ls');
```

either. Presumably because `ls` isn't a file but a built-in command. Running:

```
echo shell_exec('ls');
```

outputs:

> css demos favicon.ico images js path.php robots.txt routing.php test

which is the list of files in my root directory for the site.